# MVC jquery datepicker dateformat not set only after using it

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datetimepicker

I have the following datepicker that works so far fine:

```
$('.tmmdatepicker').datepicker({ showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "../Content/images/ico-calendar.png",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: "d M, yy",
                showAnim: "fadeIn",
                autosize:true
            });
```

Here is the razor view:

```
<tr>
    <td>Start date:</td>
    <td> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CurrentFilter.StartTime, 
        new { @class = "tmmdatepicker" , @style = "width:80px" })
   </td>
```

It works so far well, but the first time the view is loaded, the time will not be formatted in the given format (d M, yy), only after i use once the datetimepicker then the content of the EditorFor will be updated with the rule.

So, when i first enter the site:

[image: (http://i.imgur.com/nAm56.png)]

and after i use the button to select a date:

[image] <--- this is how i want to see it at the beginning.

So, is there a way to load this behavior at the beginning? (sorry, i cannot inclide direct links to pictures)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EditorTemplates.

Create file `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml` with following codes:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy") : string.Empty))
```

Comment: Good answer. To clarify a little bit for @user1839046, the problem is that your original date is coming from the server and is formatted that way. It's not until you select a new date that the format specified in the datpicker kicks in. This is why you have to format the date coming from the server as deerchao showed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are specifying datetime format in client side and seems to have totally forgotten about what's happening on the server. First time the view loads the value is rendered by asp.net view engine that converts the date into string using the current UI culture information of your project. You can change culture of your entire project or create an editor template for DateTime type as already suggested in one of the answers.